# Java Error, Incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to string

Tags: java, incompatibletypeerror

I almost finished creating this simple code, but I keep getting an error when making my input dialog box from JOptionPane and giving it a variable.

For instance:

```
name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your name?",
                    "Question",
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    iconhello,
                    null,
                    "");
```

When the name is in front, I get the error, when it is not there are no errors and my code runs smoothly, but I need to return the input into a message dialog which I create later in my code.

This is the full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name, choice, choice2, choice3, order;
    ImageIcon iconhello;//identifying the new icon created
    iconhello = new ImageIcon("hello.gif");

    ImageIcon iconcat1;
    iconcat1 = new ImageIcon("cat1.gif");

    ImageIcon iconcat7;
    iconcat7 = new ImageIcon("cat7.gif");

    ImageIcon icondrink;
    icondrink = new ImageIcon("drink.gif");

    ImageIcon iconpizza;
    iconpizza = new ImageIcon("pizza.gif");

          name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your name?",
                    "Question",
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    iconhello,
                    null,
                    "");

    Object[] possibilities= {"Chicken Sub", "Chicken Teriyaki Sub", "Tuna "
            + "Sub", "Vegetable Sub"};//creating options for user to choose from

    choice= (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What type of"
            + " subsandwich do you like? \n \"I like...\"",
    "Subsandwich",
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    iconpizza,
    possibilities,
    "Chicken Sub");

    Object[] possibilities1= {"Sprite", "Coke", "7Up", "Pepsi"};

    choice2= (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What type of"
    + " drink do you prefer to have? \n \"I prefer..\"",
    "Drink",
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    icondrink,
    possibilities1,
    "Sprite");

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please state what you would like"
            + " to have additionally",
            "Additional Request",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
            iconcat1,
            null,
            "");

    order= String.format("Your order: \n " + choice + " \n" + choice2 + 
            " \n Please enjoy!",
            "Order for: " + name + " " ,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            iconcat7,
            null);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, order);


}
```

Please, help me if you can.

Comment: every String is an Object, not every Object is a String, there lies your problem. you need to write your code as such that the compiler knows it's a String (and can not be anything else) before trying to cast it.

Answer (score 3):

The [`showInputDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) method that you're calling returns an `Object`, but you're assigning the returned value to a `String` variable. The error message is telling you that Java won't implicitly make this conversion for you, you have to do it explicitly. You've got it right a few lines later in your code.

```
choice = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What type of"
            + " subsandwich do you like? \n \"I like...\"",
    "Subsandwich",
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    iconpizza,
    possibilities,
    "Chicken Sub");
```

Comment: Thank you! :) The error was removed. But the last set of code, for the message box, with the format, the icon stated is not showing up in the message box along with the title. I'm not sure if its the format i used. Just a reminder, this part of the code is: order= String.format("Your order: \n " + choice + " \n" + choice2 + 
                " \n Please enjoy!",
                "Order for: " + name + " " ,
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                iconcat7,
                null);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, order);